# Why is wget ignoring some files in ftp transfer?

Tags: wget, ftp

I am trying to deploy a WordPress website from a test server to a production server. **wget** seems to be an efficient solution for transferring lots of files between 2 servers via FTP.

I connect to the target server, go to the /var/www folder, and I type :

```
wget -r ftp://fred:password@ftp.myserver.com/mywebsite/
```

I runs 2 minutes and then states that 2312 files have been transferred. Well, but Filezilla would find over 5000 files ! 
At first, I notice that the .htaccess file was ignored.

How does it come not all files have been handled by `wget`?

How can I specify that I need all the files to be transferred?

Comment: are you sure merely .htaccess was ignored ? moreover, all hidden files was ignored ?

Comment: Because you aren't allowed to access them... Also use ftp to ftp things.

Comment: I am sure about .htaccess, I'll check for the other files ...

Comment: To 123, actually, I can access all the files using FileZilla with the same credentials.

Comment: Have you tried `Curl` is more about streams and wget is more about copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default recursion depth limit in wget is 5. This is primarily meant for the web where a large recursion is often a mistake, but the default also applies to FTP. Large recursion could also be a problem with FTP if the server has upward-pointing symbolic links.

To make a complete mirror, pass `-l -1` to make the recursion unlimited, or better, pass the `--mirror` option.

Comment: wget -m works fine for mirroring (deploying) my website. I initially thought that .htaccess was ignored, but **ls -all** revealed the hidden file.